# Kendo on edit instead of drop down need checkbox for nullable property

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using MVC kendo grid and while editing instead of checkbox drop down is displaying. Please someone know me how I can bind checkbox on edit. Below are my code.

Model

```
public bool? IsActive { get; set; }
```

On View

```
columns.Bound(c => c.IsActive ).ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' disabled='disabled' #= IsActive ? checked='checked': '' # class='chkbx' />").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: center" });
```

Comment: https://www.telerik.com/forums/custom-checkbox-editor-for-boolean-values

Comment: https://www.telerik.com/forums/checkboxfor-editortemplate-in-grid